# Alternative rails gems for public activity that shows labels for its respective destroyed records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, public-activity

I have been trying the public_activity gem through the RailsCast tutorial and I just noticed that any data described in the activities can't be identified again once a record is destroyed, and I think this is a turn off on user experience. For example, I can only do this type of statements like

> User has deleted his post.

instead of,

> User has deleted his post entitled "Some random post".

I read the comments section of the public_activity tutorial from RailsCast and I visited a link that lead me to the Redcrumbs gem from there. After going through the documentation, I noticed that it **only tracks changes** on the records.

So, are there any other gems that can do what I need? Or should I continue to use the public_activity gem instead and just delete all the activity logs related to the destroyed record?

Answer (score 0):

There is a good solution – https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail
This gem stores information about any model you need in any particular time. Good news that gem also stores information (trail) after object has been destroyed.

Comment: I tried it recently and it's a good start. However, I think it's more convenient to add a `description` attribute to versions so that I won't repeat myself from using `reify` or getting the needed details from the records. Manually putting a description to the respective version of a record doesn't seem to work. Does paper_trail have a feature for adding a description for each version?

Comment: Parer_trail creates migration, so you can modify the paper_trail table as you wish.

Comment: I tried to add a description attribute for the versions table, and I implemented it using model callbacks. However, it doesn't seem to work. So I tried to manually add a description for a certain record from the versions table using the rails console. Unfortunately, it also doesn't work because it doesn't save when I use the `update` command.

Answer (score 0):

Creator of Redcrumbs here.

Thanks for flagging this up.

In our own apps we tracked the `deleted_at` or other relevant attribute because we were soft-deleting those objects - so we never actually encountered this problem.

I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/JonMidhir/Redcrumbs/issues/22) to deal with this and hope to have it in the next version of the gem. If you have any suggestions feel free to comment on the issue.

Thanks.